# android app with multiple sub apps

Tags: android, git, module, git-submodules, android-library

We have an app such that it should contain more sub apps. So there is a parent app P which contains other child apps c1, c2, c3 etc. These child apps can be downloaded and run stand alone from the play store as well. If the parent app P is installed on the phone and child app too are present then upon clicking a tab corresponding to child app , the child app will be launched, if child app is not present then it's activity will be shown by the parent app P.

We had started copy pasting code from parent app P to create child apps c1 , c2 etc but the changes done are not synced right now and are causing problem. The project is under git and we are thinking of creating sub modules in git and to share the code. So the app structure becomes like

```
P android studio projet structure
-appcore ( common shared code repo ) 
-c1
-c2
-c3
-com.example.p
```

where core,c1, c2, c3 will be modules in android studio having their own repository which have the code that needs to be put inside P.

Each child app will have structure as below

```
c1 android studio structure :

    -appcore
    -c1
    -com.example.c1
```

So basically the child app c1 gets common shared code between all apps form appcore repo and makes changes in c1 repo which can be shared with other apps which add c1 repo as submodule and has the application specific files (like splash screen etc ) in com.example.c1 package.

Is there any better way for doing this ?

Comment: Maybe work with product flavors?(https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html). You will still have to think about your project structure, but you could include different code for the different flavors.

Comment: "better" is very relative, but an option to avoid git sub modules is to setup a local maven repo from all the common code and then all the individual projects can use that code by simply including the `compile` directive on their `gradle.build`

Comment: @Budius We are thinking of git submodules as they provide two way communications and other people can commit and push changes in shared code which I think is not possible with maven repo.

Comment: on this option the shared code would still be a git repo just like usual. The maven is just to have a central (but local inside the company) place for the java bytecode to be and where everybody can use it.